# I am looking for good read-ups for Java programming using app-engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to make a website using Java on google app-engine. Can you suggest any good readups to get me up to speed on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to read is of course Google's own overview of Java for App Engine:

- Google code/Google App Engine Java

  - [Overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html)
  - [Getting  Started](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/)
- Google code/YouTube channel

  - [Google App Engine - Early Look at Java Language Support](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3GT4-m_6RQ)
  - [Google I/O 2009 - App Engine: Now Serving Java](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofn8QYEVyhA)

As far as online step-by-step tutorials, there are several good ones:

- IBM developerWorks/Java Technology/Technical library/

  - [Google App Engine for Java: Part 1: Rev it up!](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej1/)
  - [Google App Engine for Java, Part 2: Building the killer app](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej2/)
  - [Google App Engine for Java: Part 3: Persistence and relationships](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej3.html)

If you need to read more, you can buy one of the many books available on the subject:

- [Beginning Java Google App Engine](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430225539), by Kyle Roche, Jeff Douglas (ISBN13: 978-1-4302-2553-9)

Answer (score 2):

I found [this free ebook](http://gaejexperiments.wordpress.com/) to be very useful with real world code samples.